# Pump command output as function argument

Tags: linux, bash, logs, function, output

I have this extremely simple function in my script:

```
# Used for debug tracing.
log()
{
    :
    echo "log: $1"
}
```

The idea is to be able to customize/turn off logging at a single place. Very crude.

Now I want my script to produce absolutely no output when in release configuration. The only solution I have thought of, but extremely unDRY:

```
TMPFILE='/tmp/tempfilewithpossiblyuniquename'
cmd 1>"$TMPFILE" 2>"$TMPFILE"
cat "$TMPFILE" | xargs log
rm "$TMPFILE"
```

for *every single command*. How to improve on this?

---

EDIT: I want to collect *all* output to `stdout` and `stderr` and channel it through `log()`. Then `log()` can choose to disregard everything, to log to a file, to print etc.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no output is simple, just redirect the script's `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
exec >/dev/null 2>&1
```

That will affect the shell itself, and any commands it executes afterwards. Run that conditionally to choose where the output is redirected.

```
if [ "$output_to_file" = 1 ]; then
    exec > "$outputfilename" 2>&1
elif [ "$output_suppress" = 1 ]; then
    exec > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Note, that suppressing *all* output isn't probably a good idea. The user is very likely to want *some* notification for errors.

---

If you insist on passing output through the function (and are running Bash/ksh/Zsh), you could use process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
mangle_output() {
    # do something smarter here
    while read -r line; do
        echo "output: $line";
    done;
}
# redirect stdout and stderr to the function
exec > >(mangle_output) 2>&1
echo something that produces output
```

Though note that processing the output with a shell loop isn't a very good idea, in the least it's slow. See: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/170373). If all you want is redirection a file, or to `/dev/null`, just use `exec` to set up redirections.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question. What I wanted to say, it that all output should be routed through `log()`.

Comment: @Vorac, mmhm. edited.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that function will only log the first "word" of anything sent to it, since you use `$1` rather than `"$*"`.

Secondly, there are (as is oft the case with POSIX) myriad ways to do this sort of thing.  I would probably go with something like:

```
log() {
    cat - >> "$logfile"
}

do_stuff | log
```

But you could also:

```
(
    do_stuff
    do_more_stuff
) >> "$logfile"
```

As for completely suppressing all output -- that is something that is usually best left for the invoking environment (e. g. `./thing 1> /dev/null 2> &1`) rather than locking it down "in code" as it were.  That said:

```
squashout="true"  # comment this out to stop killing output
if ! [[ "true" = "${squashout-false}" ]]; then 
  # Redirect stdout and stderr to the null device.  
  exec 1> /dev/null
  exec 2> /dev/null
fi
```